# Reverse engineering from binary or ipa

Tags: ios

I lost the code of an app I wrote some years ago...the game structure was pretty cool and would be good to have it back...

So can I reverse a binary into...something? I mean at least class tree...

I've this[image]

and the ipa (yes I saved it and not the code source, pretty smart eh?)

I saw this link but don't know how to use objc-helper-plugin-ida! Never used python before

otool gives:

[image]

Comment: we can only answer a specific question, this is too unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Use IDA Pro 6.5 Demo (available for free from http://hex-rays.com)
It supports ObjC by default

Answer (score 3):

You can use Radare2, IDA Pro or Hopper. You'll need to reverse it and this might take more time than rewriting it. Also have a look at *this* post: [Possibilities for reverse engineering an ipa file to its source](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/possibilities-for-reverse-engineering-an-ipa-file-to-its-source)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SmartDec](http://derevenets.com/) decompiler too. The IDA Pro plugin does support Mach-O.

Answer (score 1):

To get the basic class structure back, you can use [classdump](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/).

It generates declarations for the classes, methods, categories and protocols. This is the same information provided by using ‘otool -ov’, but presented as normal Objective-C declarations, so it is much more compact and readable.