# Decompile and recompile C?

Tags: c, decompile

What tools produce C code that does not produce errors when you try to recompile it again? Can Hex-Rays decompiler convert everything to project files in a single folder and just compile it?

Comment: Regarding the limitations of machine-code decompilation, see this answer:  http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311/why-are-machine-code-decompilers-less-capable-than-for-example-those-for-the-clr/312#312

Comment: There have been a long story already on this topic as SO. Better to look through: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273145/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-windows-exe-or-at-least-view-the-assembly

Answer (score 5):

The primary purpose of [decompilation](http://www.debugmode.com/dcompile/) is not to produce code that is compiled back with no errors, but rather recover logical flow of a binary. Hex-Ras Decompiler comes with its own set of limitation noted in [Hex-Rays Decompiler Manual](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/limit.shtml), to mention few:

```
Below are the most important limitations of our decompilers (all processors):
     * exception handling is not supported
     * type recovery is not performed
     * global program analysis is not performed
```

Comment: My question was: Is there any decompiler that produces code that can be recompiled easily?

Comment: @user8005: Your question is and I quote: "...does not produce errors when your try to compile it"... There is no tools like that.

Comment: When the source is C# and not C, ILSpy works great btw...

Comment: @user8005: sure...However, your question is about C...not C#.

Comment: In fact, it would be trivial to produce cleanly compiling C code that simply inlines any questionable assembly code that it can't understand.  As PSS points out, recompilation is not the point of decompilation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can recompile C but the decompilation has be be manual. As far as I know there is no automatical tool that provide Recompilable C from assembly.

`ddisasm` is a tool to make recompiling asm from a binary file.

A good starts should be to:

1. Disassemble your program to assembly language with `ddisasm`.
2. Use ldd tools to list libraries from the old binary
3. Recompile it with gcc/g++ makefile with linked libraries
4. Rewrite a function from assembly language to C.

And back to the step 2 again and again until your program is enough decompiled for you.

Note that `ddisasm` is really slow: it requires around 150 GB of swap / ram to disassemble a 100 MB file.